# Avatars are still move and slide after placing them in AR World Unity - Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am currently working on an [augmented reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality) (AR) app, and I am facing the following issue:

After placing an avatar in the AR world, it still moves and slides on the *ground* while I am approaching its place. Why does that happen?

I am using Unity 2018.3.0 and [Vuforia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuforia_Augmented_Reality_SDK) 8.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

**Use an Anchor -** 
Anchor points are persistent locations in the world space that are continuously tracked as the world space grows and changes in a Ground Plane session. Use an Anchor when you want your content to be positioned as accurately as possible at a specific location in the world. 
[image: Vuforia Ground plane API overview, Credit: Vuforia]

For more reference please refer to official doc:
https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/ground-plane-guide.html

Comment: let me explian my case:
i have slider of avatars Icon , when i click the avatar icon i load it to the scene and place it at the PlaneIndicator point position, how gonna take the anchor ? 
or how can i relate my avatar to the anchor position ?

Comment: Sorry, but as per my understanding: Create an empty GameObject and Anchor it in the real world (So object will be there in real word position but its empty/invisible). Now spawn your Avatar as a child of previously created empty gameobject.

Comment: could you right a sample code for this and how to link it with the desired GameObject ?